# "Add Record" gives "Can't go to specified record" after first use Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a command button in a form that allows users to add a new record. The command only works the first time you click it after the form is opened. I can navigate through the records without any errors and the first time you add a record after the form is opened will not give errors. Once you try to add a second record, the "Can't go to the specified record" error message is displayed.

I can make edits in the query without a problem and I can edit things without a problem. If I close out of the form and reopen it I can add a new record without issues. Anyone have ideas?

Using VBA, it's the standard add-new code, nothing else. Posted all the code for this form below. Some of the command buttons listed are in macros, don't know if that makes a difference.

```
Private Sub add_Click()
  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub

Private Sub edit_info_Click()
    Date_of_Echo.Locked = False
    ID.Locked = False
    AoV.Locked = False
    AI.Locked = False
    MR.Locked = False
    TR.Locked = False
    TR_velocity.Locked = False
    PA_pressures.Locked = False
    LVeDD.Locked = False
    LVeSD.Locked = False
    RV_function.Locked = False
    comments.Locked = False
    Me.next.Visible = False
    Me.previous.Visible = False
    Me.first.Visible = False
    Me.last.Visible = False
    Me.add.Visible = False
    Me.save.Visible = True
    Me.save.SetFocus
    Me.edit_info.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub Form_Current()
   If Me.NewRecord Then
    Me.recordcounter.Caption = "New Record"
    Me.next.Visible = False
    Me.previous.Visible = False
    Me.first.Visible = False
    Me.last.Visible = False
    Me.add.Visible = False
    Me.edit_info.Visible = False
    Me.save.Visible = True
    Date_of_Echo.Locked = False
    ID.Locked = False
    AoV.Locked = False
    AI.Locked = False
    MR.Locked = False
    TR.Locked = False
    TR_velocity.Locked = False
    PA_pressures.Locked = False
    LVeDD.Locked = False
    LVeSD.Locked = False
    RV_function.Locked = False
    comments.Locked = False
   Else
    Me.recordcounter.Caption = "Record " & Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & Me.Recordset.RecordCount
    Me.next.Visible = True
    Me.previous.Visible = True
    Me.first.Visible = True
    Me.last.Visible = True
    Me.add.Visible = True
    Me.edit_info.Visible = True
    Me.save.Visible = False
    End If
 End Sub
Private Sub save_Click()
DoCmd.save
    Me.previous.Visible = True
    Me.first.Visible = True
    Me.last.Visible = True
    Me.next.Visible = True
    Me.add.Visible = True
    Me.edit_info.Visible = True
    Me.recordcounter.Caption = "Record " & Me.CurrentRecord & " of " & Me.Recordset.RecordCount
    Me.add.SetFocus
    Me.save.Visible = False
    Date_of_Echo.Locked = True
    ID.Locked = True
    AoV.Locked = True
    AI.Locked = True
    MR.Locked = True
    TR.Locked = True
    TR_velocity.Locked = True
    PA_pressures.Locked = True
    LVeDD.Locked = True
    LVeSD.Locked = True
    RV_function.Locked = True
    comments.Locked = True

End Sub
Private Sub next_Click()
    On Error GoTo Err_cmdLastRecord_Click

    Me.AllowAdditions = False
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

Exit_cmdLastRecord_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdLastRecord_Click:
    MsgBox " There are no more records ", vbExclamation, ""
    Resume Exit_cmdLastRecord_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Please expand on how you are performing this.  If it is a macro or if it is VBA.  Stackoverflow loves code so when possible post it with your question!

Comment: Sorry about that, editing question now to include code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first thought is that your record isn't saving before you try to go to a new record so try this and see if it fixes the issue.

```
Private Sub add_Click()

    If Me.Dirty Then
        Me.Dirty = False
    End If

  DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

End Sub
```

Comment: That actually made it so that I cannot add a new record at all. For future reference though, what does that command do?

Comment: Basically it just means if there were changes, then save them. Odd that it wouldn't allow it to go to a new record.  Try the old fashion way of `DoCmd.Save` just before your new record command.

Comment: That takes it back to what it was before. I can add a new record using the command button when I initially open the form, but not after I add a new record.

Comment: Actually I don't think AllowAdditions gets toggled back on anywhere when you click the next button.  If you turn it on just before `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` does that work?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still having this problem, I can't explain why it's happening, but here's a work around:

Reset the `AllowAdditionsProperty` on the form:

```
Me.[form_name].Form.AllowAdditions = False
Me.[form_name].Form.AllowAdditions = True
```

This was a very strange issue because my code had been working fine for weeks. I was using something like this:

```
Me.frm.SetFocus
   DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
     !Field1 = value1
     !Field2 = value2
```

It was working great, and then out of the blue I started getting the "Can't go to Specified Record" error, even though I had made no changes to the code. The form settings were fine and I could add records all day long in the underlying table. I even checked the form's `AllowAdditions` property in the *Immediate* window, and that showed it was set to `True`. But I tried this work around, and it worked.

Now I add those two lines after every instance of `Docmd.GoToNewRoecord`, `acNewRecord` and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I have mentioned with the same problem is that you should check the Form data source query. Are all the FIELDS available, are the JOINS correct?
In my case I changed indexed joins from text fields to numeric and it needed update also in Form Data source query.